# Ajax response looks undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to get the ajax response and attribute it to a variable (let's say _has_weekend_hollidays) as follows:

---

JS Call:

```
_has_weekend_hollidays = checkWeekendHollidays( _i );
console.log ( checkWeekendHollidays( _i ) );
```

---

AJAX Call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./directory/ajax_check_weekend_hollidays.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
            start_date: _date1,
            final_date: _date2 
          }
}).done(function (_result) {
    return ( _first_weekday == 0 || _last_weekday_id >= 6 || _result!="0" );
}).fail(function (_result) {
    console.log("ERROR:" + _resultado);
});
```

---

The AJAX _result is OK but the return is not working.

So console.log shows **undefined**.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does the function `checkWeekendHollidays` do? what does it return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the result to continue, do your work after the Ajax callback.

It's `undefined` because there are no variable return by Ajax:

```
{
    url: "./directory/ajax_check_weekend_hollidays.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
            start_date: _date1,
            final_date: _date2 
          }
}
```

This line:

`return ( _first_weekday == 0 || _last_weekday_id >= 6 || _result!="0" );`

is not executed until Ajax is "Done".

It you wish to log the return data, use console.log in the return function.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./directory/ajax_check_weekend_hollidays.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
            start_date: _date1,
            final_date: _date2 
          }
}).done(function (_result) {
    console.log(_first_weekday == 0 || _last_weekday_id >= 6 || _result!="0");
    //do something else here too
}).fail(function (_result) {
    console.log("ERROR:" + _resultado);
});
```

Comment: Thx but how can I get the console.log value to use in the JS? I mean, I need the holidays information in the bank that is got by the ajax to check if the period contains holidays or weekends.

Comment: @AnaSouza Ajax is usually for non UI blocking updates. If you wish to use the result of Ajax for other logics, do so by  moving whatever you need to do inside the ".done" block. That's just how I did btw, wait a bit to see if there are better solutions from other developers.

Comment: OK! Perfect! It works now! I'm a backend programmer suffering with AJAX. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AnaSouza Good to know, please mark this as accepted answer if it helps. : )

Comment: Someone disliked it. Not me. Thank you again. It was accepted.